# What is the distribution of city sizes for cities whose rank size obeys Zipf's law?

Tags: distributions, zipf

Been wracking my brain over this one but can't quite get it.

I want a distribution for the population size of randomly-chosen cities, where I can assume the city's rank obeys Zipf's law with a known largest city.

I can sample this by first uniformly sampling a city's rank, and then looking up its population size as max_city_pop/rank.

But, to do some stuff involving a copula that connects city size to other attributes (like birth rate, urbanicity, health outcomes, etc), I'd like to just have a parametric distribution for city sizes.

My math is feeling a bit weak and I've not been able to figure out how to do this. I suspect it's really simple, but I'm stumped. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always good to take a lunch break...

By assumption, the rank of a set size $R$ is uniformly distributed with probability $\frac{1}{R}$.  For convenience, I will allow rank to be a continuous variable with density $\frac{1}{R}$ over the domain $r\in(0,R)$,
$$p(r)=\int_0^r \frac{dr}{R}=\frac{r}{R}$$

By Zipf's law, the size $N$ of the city rank $r$ is a function $N=\frac{N_{max}}{r}$, and so the inverse is $r=\frac{N_{max}}{N}$.

By the standard Jacobian transformation for a change of variables, we have

$$p(N)= \frac{N_{max}}{R}\frac{1}{N^2}$$

The bounds of integration are defined by modeling choices and normalization

$$1 = \displaystyle \int_a^b dN p(N)=\frac{N_{max}}{R}\left(\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b}\right)$$

For my purposes, where I want something qualitatively like my set of real cities but I do not need it to be real cities, it's reasonable to allow the upper bound to be infinite, $b\rightarrow \infty$, and so lower bound nees to be

$$a=\frac{R}{N_{max}}$$

or, the size of the smallest city under consideration.

So anyway, the distribution of city size goes like $N^{-2}$.

**EDIT** I suppose I can make things prettier by changing variables again to $N'=\frac{R}{N_{max}}N$ which gives

$$p(N')=\frac{1}{N'^2}$$

over the domain $N'\in(1,\infty)$. Then just convert back to the appropriate scale when I'm done.

**EDIT 2**. This is the [Pareto distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution) with $\alpha =1$. Looks like I just learned something basic!